# Closing and Unmapping POSIX shared memory object

Tags: c, posix, shared-memory

I am currently working on something using POSIX named semaphores and shared memory and I've read from the man pages that all open named semaphores are automatically closed on process termination. Is this also the case for shared memory objects, are they also closed and unmapped or simply just closed? I cannot find any information about this on the man pages.

Comment: `man shm_overview`: *Persistence POSIX shared memory objects have kernel persistence: a shared memory object will exist until the system is shut  down,  or  until  all  processes  have unmapped the object and it has been deleted with shm_unlink(3)*

Comment: What does this question mean? If the process no longer exists, where would it be mapped?

Comment: It's still mapped in *other* processes that share it, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Upon calling shm_unlink(), which will remove a shared memory object name, and, once all processes have unmapped the object, de-allocate and destroy the contents of the associated memory region, do I have to also call munmap() somewhere in the code, or will the process termination take care of the unmapping?

Comment: Memory mappings are a per-process property.  They do not survive termination of the process to which they pertain.  But multiple process may simultaneously map the same shared-memory object -- in fact, that's usually the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question seems to be about how and when to clean up POSIX shared memory used by one or more processes, or possibly about how to avoid shared memory being cleaned up prematurely.

POSIX shared memory is designed on a model intentionally similar to regular file access.  In particular,

- `shm_open()` will create and open a new, persistent shared-memory object or simply open an existing one, depending on whether there already is one with the specified name.
- that region can be opened by other processes (and therefore must persist) until it is unlinked via `shm_unlink()`.
- a shared memory region lives after its unlinking as long as any process has it open, but it can no longer be opened via `shm_open()`.
- mapping a shared memory region via `mmap()` has the effect of holding it open while that mapping is in place, independent of the file descriptor used to map it

Moreover, memory mappings for a shared-memory region are in most respects the same as mappings for regular files.  Mappings are per-process properties; they do not survive termination of the process to which they pertain.  Mappings are preserved (duplicated) across `fork()`s.

On some systems, shared memory regions may even be accessible via the file system.  Aside from the different functions for managing them, their most significant difference from regular files is probably that they do not persist across reboots.

Thus, you do not need to worry about termination of a process unwantedly tearing down a shared memory region that is in use by other processes.  On the other hand, you can arrange for shared-memory regions to be cleaned up automatically by unlinking them after every process that needs to obtain access by name has done so.  If you intend to grant access only to child processes (and maybe their children, etc.) then you can unlink immediately after creation.  Children will inherit the mapping when you fork them.

So, in response to the actual question:

> Is this also the case for shared memory objects, are they also closed and unmapped or simply just closed?

Shared memory objects open and / or mapped by a process are both closed and unmapped when that process terminates, but they are not automatically unlinked.  They will persist at least until manually unlinked or the system is rebooted.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this also the case for shared memory objects, are they also closed
>   and unmapped or simply just closed?

They are unmapped but they may continue to occupy space in the backing filesystem (usually tmpfs/shmfs for /dev/shm on memory) if they are not explicitly unlinked.

On FreeBSD it is possible to get this automatic unlinking with the non-portable SHM_ANON flag.  If you want this kind of behaviour you can either:

1. Use mmap(2) with the MAP_ANONYMOUS flag and share file descriptors via fork(2) or send them to other processes with sendmsg(2) using Unix domain sockets.
2. Use System V shared memory with the IPC_RMID flag, which automatically destroys the memory segment after the last process detaches it.  The dettachment happens when the process dies or calls shmdt(2).
3. Use the newer Linux-only memfd_create(2) system call.

Comment: I'm not sure what this answer means.  "No" to what?  What is made possible with `SHM_ANON`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've just edited to quote the question I was answering.

Comment: Well, "no" doesn't seem to answer the question, which I read as an either / or, not a yes / no.  If you mean "neither", then I think you're mistaken: process termination certainly removes that process's mappings of any POSIX shared memory and closes its handles on the same.  What it does not do is unlink the shared memory region.

Comment: @JohnBollinger if what you're saying is true then you've answered my question

Comment: @JohnBollinger I've just edited it again to be more precise.  Hope it answers your question.

Comment: That is much clearer and seems correct.  It is not me who downvoted, though, so I can't help you with that.